# Which package should I file a bug against for pen input?

Tags: 13.10, suspend, bug-reporting, touchscreen, fujitsu-siemens

I have a [Fujitsu LifeBook T900](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/fujitsu-lifebook-t900/4507-3121_7-34183957.html), and I have a problem with Ubuntu on it. This laptop has a touch screen meant to be used with an accompanying stylus (i.e. it only works with the stylus, and not with finger input). Under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (which this laptop previously ran), input with the stylus always worked flawlessly. However, since doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10, the screen stops responding to stylus input after I suspend the laptop and wake it up again (the keyboard and touchpad continue working though). This means if I want to handwrite notes or draw on my laptop, I need to restart my machine if I have closed the lid, which is pretty annoying.

So, my question is this: if I were to file a bug report for this behavior, which package should I file it against? Perhaps it could also be useful if somebody could tell me what I should include in the report which would make it more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input-related issues generally have to do with X.org (also known as X11, also known as X server).

However, this might be a kernel bug, as the symptoms occur only after suspension. The problem may be that the kernel fails to wake up your device.

Therefore I'd report a bug against Linux:

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

That command will attach many useful information about your hardware that will help figuring out what's wrong. In case it turns out that the problem is not caused by the kernel, someone from the bugsquad will "forward" the bug to the right project.

Comment: Thanks! I have filed my particular bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1251441), in case anyone is interested.